# Set Config is not a function

Tags: javascript, store, propertygrid

I have some store, which is formed data. On panel it looks how "fieldName" and text field (in depension from invoked form). For example, on one form is displayed "name document" and field, on another: date of selling and date field. Data is formed dynamicly

Here is store:

```
tableTempStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: objectUrlAddress,
    baseParams: {
        'objectID': objectID
    },
    root: 'Fields',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Type',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Value'
    }, {
        name: 'IsRequired',
        type: 'bool'
    }, {
        name: 'Identifier'
    }, {
        name: 'Data'
    }],
    listeners: {
        load: function(obj, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(rec) {

                var item = null;
                switch (rec.get('Type')) {
                    case 0:
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                        item.allowDecimals = true;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                }
                if (item != null) {
                    grid.add(item);
                    columnsTable = item.__proto__.constructor.xtype;
                        source[item.fieldLabel] = '';
                        grid.setSource(source);
                        var cm = grid.getColumnModel();
                        var valCol = cm.getColumnAt(1);
                        if (columnsTable=='textfield')
                        {
                            valCol.setConfig({
                                header: 'Поле', 
                                id:'name',
                               editor:  {xtype: 'textfield'}
                            });
                        }
                        else if (columnsTable == 'combo')
                        {
                            valCol.setConfig({
                               xtype: new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.ComboBox()),
                               allowBlank: false,
                            });
                        }
                        else if (columnsTable == 'datefield')
                        {
                            valCol.setConfig({
                               xtype: new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.DateField()),
                               allowBlank: false,
                            });
                        }
                }
            });
            grid.setSource(source);
        }
    }
});
```

But i have some error: setConfig in not a function. Why, if he works in others events.

Here is Grid:

```
grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
        title: 'Properties Grid',
        id: 'propGrid',
        customEditors: 
        {
            tableValue: new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.ComboBox())
        },
        autoFill: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        width: 600
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property Grid in ExtJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950926/property-grid-in-extjs)