# Property Grid in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs3, propertygrid

I have some store, which is formed data. On panel it looks how "fieldName" and text field (in depension from invoked form). For example, on one form is displayed "name document" and field, on another: date of selling and date field. Data is formed dynamicly

Here is store:

```
tableTempStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: objectUrlAddress,
    baseParams: {
        'objectID': objectID
    },
    root: 'Fields',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Type',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Value'
    }, {
        name: 'IsRequired',
        type: 'bool'
    }, {
        name: 'Identifier'
    }, {
        name: 'Data'
    }],
    listeners: {
        load: function(obj, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(rec) {

                var item = null;
                switch (rec.get('Type')) {
                    case 0: // int
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = ! isRequired;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                    case 1: // demical
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = ! isRequired;
                        item.allowDecimals = true;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                    case 2: // text
                        item = new Ext.form.TextField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.allowBlank = ! isRequired;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        if (item.id == 'DocumentName') {
                            if (optype == "create") {
                                item.disabled = false;
                            } else {
                                item.disabled = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3: // date
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item = new Ext.form.DateField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.format = 'd.m.y H:i';
                        item.allowBlank = ! isRequired;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        item.emptyText = 'дд.мм.гггг чч:мм';
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        break;
                    case 4: // enum
                        var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(rec.get('EnumList'));
                        var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function(k) { return [k, dataValues[k]] });
                        item = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                            typeAhead: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            forceSelection:true,
                            editable: false,
                            hiddenName: rec.get('Identifier'),
                            mode: 'local',
                            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                fields: [
                                    {name: 'myId', type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'displayText'}
                                ],
                                data: dataArray
                            }),
                            valueField: 'myId',
                            displayField: 'displayText',
                            disabled: editDisabled

                        });

                        item.id = '_' + rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.allowBlank = ! isRequired;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                    case 5: // SQL
                        var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(rec.get('EnumList'));
                        var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function(k) { return [k, dataValues[k]] });
                        item = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                            typeAhead: true,
                            width: '100%',
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            forceSelection:true,
                            editable: false,
                            hiddenName: rec.get('Identifier'),
                            mode: 'local',
                            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                fields: [
                                    {name: 'myId', type: 'string'},
                                    {name: 'displayText'}
                                ],
                                data: dataArray
                            }),
                            valueField: 'myId',
                            displayField: 'displayText',
                            disabled: editDisabled
                        });
                        item.id = '_' + rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.allowBlank = ! isRequired;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                        }
                if (item != null) {
                    grid.add(item);
                    tableValue = Ext.getCmp('propGrid').doLayout();
                    source[item.fieldLabel] = tableValue;
                    //grid.doLayout();
                }
            });
            grid.setSource(source);
        }
    }
});
```

This code had worked with form, but I need to use Property Grid. I know, how displayed field name ("document name" and etc.), but I don't understand, how displayed text field or etc. For form I had used doLayout. How can I do this?

I tryed used customEditors, but he don't work with store!

Here is Grid:

```
grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    id: 'propGrid',
    autoFill: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    width: 600
});
```

Please, help me!

UPDATING

Here's updating store:

```
someStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        storeId: 'myStore',
        url: objectUrlAddress,
        baseParams: {
            'objectID' : objectID
        },
        root: 'Fields',
        fields: [
            {name: 'Hint'},
            {name:'Type', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Value'},
            {name: 'Index', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'IsRequired', type:'bool'},
            {name: 'Identifier'},
            {name: 'EnumList'},
            {name: 'Directory'},
            {name: 'Data'}
        ]});
```

Here's updating grid:

```
var mainGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        id: 'tableId',
        height:300,
        width: '100%',
        clicksToEdit:1,
        frame: true,
        store: someStore,
        columns: 
        [
        {header: 'Объект'},
        {header: 'Значение', dataIndex: 'Value', editor: {xtype: 'textfield'},
        getEditor: function(record) {
                   var xtype = null,
                    args = {
                    fieldLabel: record.get('Hint'),
                    allowBlank: !record.get('IsRequired'),
                    value: record.get('Data'),
                    disabled: false
                };
                switch (record.get('Type')) {
                    case 0: // int
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Number';
                        args.allowDecimals = false;
                    break;
                    case 1: // decimal
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Number';
                        args.allowDecimals = true;
                    break;
                    case 2: // text
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Text';
                    break;
                    case 3: // date
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Date';
                        args.emptyText = 'дд.мм.гггг чч:мм';
                        args.format = 'd.m.y H:i';
                    break;
                    case 4: // enum
                    case 5: // sql
                        var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(record.get('EnumList'));
                        var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function(k) { return [k, dataValues[k]] });

                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox ';
                        args.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            fields: [
                                {name: 'myId', type: 'string'},
                                {name: 'displayText'}
                            ],
                            data: dataArray
                        });
                    break;
                }

                return new Ext.grid.CellEditor({
                    field: Ext.create(xtype, args)
                });
              }
            }
        ]
        });
```

But table is empty, what i doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

See the partially implemented solution in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mth)

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'myStore',
    fields:[ 'Type', 'Value', 'IsRequired', 'Identifier', 'Data'],
    data: [
        {
            "Type": 0,
            "IsRequired": false,
            "Identifier": "id-1",
            "Data": 1001
        },
        {
            "Type": 0,
            "IsRequired": true,
            "Identifier": "id-2",
            "Data": 2002
        },
        {
            "Type": 1,
            "IsRequired": true,
            "Identifier": "id-3",
            "Data": 0.71
        },
        {
            "Type": 3,
            "IsRequired": true,
            "Identifier": "id-4",
            "Data": "24.10.18 00:00"
        }
    ]
});

Ext.create({
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    xtype: 'grid',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    plugins: ['cellediting'],
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore'),
    selModel: 'cellmodel',
    columns: [
        { text: 'Identifier', dataIndex: 'Identifier' },
        {
            text: 'Data',
            dataIndex: 'Data',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield' // will default to this
            },
            getEditor: function(record) {
                var xtype = null,
                    args = {
                    fieldLabel: record.get('Hint'),
                    allowBlank: !record.get('IsRequired'),
                    value: record.get('Data'),
                    disabled: false
                };

                console.log({
                    type: record.get('Type')
                });

                switch (record.get('Type')) {
                    case 0: // int
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Number';
                        args.allowDecimals = false;
                    break;
                    case 1: // decimal
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Number';
                        args.allowDecimals = true;
                    break;
                    case 2: // text
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Text';
                    break;
                    case 3: // date
                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.Date';
                        args.emptyText = 'дд.мм.гггг чч:мм';
                        args.format = 'd.m.y H:i';
                    break;
                    case 4: // enum
                    case 5: // sql
                        var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(record.get('EnumList'));
                        var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function(k) { return [k, dataValues[k]] });

                        xtype = 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox ';
                        args.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            fields: [
                                {name: 'myId', type: 'string'},
                                {name: 'displayText'}
                            ],
                            data: dataArray
                        });
                    break;
                }

                if (!xtype) {
                    return false;
                }

                return Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
                    field: Ext.create(xtype, args)
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

*PS: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, consider elaborating a bit more on the use case in your description.*

Comment: Thanks for response. I want achive a changing column type in dependence from case in store. I know how display "field label" (in left side), but how to make corresponding data types i don't know. I try used setColumnModel, but he not work.

Comment: Could you explain what the objective is for this? What is the use-case? Something like: "I want to allow users to maintain variables with different data types in a grid"

Comment: Display name and fields from store - that's objective. Use-case need for dynamically display variables in grid in dependence from what grid i want open. In form it works with doLayou, but this it method not work here.

Comment: What type of fields should be possible? In your example it seems like you only have to cater for integer and decimal data types...

Comment: Right, but in example lies part of source code. I'll updating my post, take a look P.S. In different grid calling different types in a different order.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my the answer & fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mth)

Comment: Thank you very much, i try this tomorrow and will tell here

Comment: Oh, forgot ask: you used EditorGrid or PropertyGrid?

Comment: Please, answer me, it is important!

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle? I hope my answer helped you at least a little bit. Good luck!

Comment: I can't checked, because i take my values from files in my program. I need create Property Grid of Editor Grid? Because i have ExtJs 3.0, and some values in your example can't working in 3.0. Thanks you advice

Comment: I have a error: record.get is not function. What is it mean? How i can solve this?